Calling stored procedure via ADF pipeline does not load the data even though it is (ADF) pipeline success
I have few SQL Stored Procedures which are doing data loads to the various data warehouse tables.
I am executing these stored procedure via ADF pipeline using Stored procedure task as attached, however I realised it is not loading the data even though ADF pipelines run successfully.
Please let me know if anyone has come across this before and remediation actions.
My environment is Azure Synapses and ADF pipelines
I deleted the target table and expecting to load the data via ADF pipeline which is calling the stored procedure, but no data being loaded,

You said as attached? where is your attachement?
